# How to Ws-Policy in weblogic 12c

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic12c

I'm code  web service   ws-policy in  Eclipse. 
     I want to do like this link  http://kingsfleet.blogspot.com/2008/12/simple-custom-policy-example-using-jax.html    but
    error  WSSecurityContext , because   weblogic 12c  has not library or not?

```
  rc.put(WSSecurityContext.CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_LIST, credProviders);
```

I need advice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this before, I think the solution for generating a client code to invoke ws secured web service is manually creating wsse headers.
Example how to implement `SOAPHandler` class:

```
package com.javadb.ws.example;

import java.util.Set;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPEnvelope;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPHeader;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext;

/**
 *
 * @author www.javadb.com
 */
public class HeaderHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext smc) {

        Boolean outboundProperty = (Boolean) smc.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

        if (outboundProperty.booleanValue()) {

            SOAPMessage message = smc.getMessage();

            try {

                SOAPEnvelope envelope = smc.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
                SOAPHeader header = envelope.addHeader();

                SOAPElement security =
                        header.addChildElement("Security", "wsse", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");

                SOAPElement usernameToken =
                        security.addChildElement("UsernameToken", "wsse");
                usernameToken.addAttribute(new QName("xmlns:wsu"), "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");

                SOAPElement username =
                        usernameToken.addChildElement("Username", "wsse");
                username.addTextNode("TestUser");

                SOAPElement password =
                        usernameToken.addChildElement("Password", "wsse");
                password.setAttribute("Type", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText");
                password.addTextNode("TestPassword");

                //Print out the outbound SOAP message to System.out
                message.writeTo(System.out);
                System.out.println("");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            try {

                //This handler does nothing with the response from the Web Service so
                //we just print out the SOAP message.
                SOAPMessage message = smc.getMessage();
                message.writeTo(System.out);
                System.out.println("");

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }


        return outboundProperty;

    }

    public Set getHeaders() {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        return null;
    }

    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        return true;
    }

    public void close(MessageContext context) {
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}
```

Follow below link for more information:
http://www.javadb.com/using-a-message-handler-to-alter-the-soap-header-in-a-web-service-client/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12356864)

Comment: Thank you for your useful warning. It is edited now.